# Creating multiple imageCollections in loop in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am writing a large loop and for each iteration, I want to use / manipulate a different imageCollection in order to use as little memory as possible.

However, it seems that this is impossible due to how imageCollection() interprets what's a string and what's not. Does anyone know why or, if it's not impossible, what GEE specifications are?

Here is some code:

```
// Make a list of Features.
var features = [
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(97.58, 24.36), {name: 'sample1'}),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(99.45, 20.26), {name: 'sample2'}),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(93.24, 21.42), {name: 'sample3'}),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(96.13, 24.12), {name: 'sample4'}),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(96.88, 22.48), {name: 'sample5'})
];

// Create a FeatureCollection from the list and print it.
var points = ee.FeatureCollection(features);

// list containing 3 satellite sources
var sat =
  ee.List(["LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_TOA",
    "MODIS/006/MOD09GQ", 
  "MODIS/006/MOD09GA", 
  ]);

//this doesn't work
print(ee.ImageCollection(ee.String(sat.get(0))));

//nor this
var test = sat.map(ee.ImageCollection().
                  .filterDate('2015-06-23', '2020-01-31');
print('test', test);

//nor this
var satindex = ee.List.sequence(0,2);

satindex.size().evaluate(function(nlist){
  for(var j = 0; j<nlist; j++){
    var satname = ee.String(sat.get(j))
    print(satname)

    var satimgs = ee.ImageCollection(satname)
                  .filterDate('2015-06-23', '2020-01-31')
    print(satimgs)
  }
});

//but this one does work
var mytest = function(satellite){
  var imgs = ee.ImageCollection(satellite)
    .filterDate('2015-06-23', '2020-01-31')
    .filterBounds(points)
  return imgs
};
print('mytest', mytest("LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_TOA"));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to use client side strings to load an ImageCollection. For example:

```
// Client-side list containing 3 satellite sources
var sat =
  ["LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_TOA",
    "MODIS/006/MOD09GQ", 
  "MODIS/006/MOD09GA", 
  ];

//this does work
print(ee.ImageCollection(ee.String(sat[0])));
```

> //but this one does work (albeit too many images)

You will have 'too many images' as you are now asking for ALL images worldwide in between the start and end date defined. That are a lot of images. Probably, you want to filter the images first on a Region of Interest. Subsequently, use `filterBounds(geometry)` before printing an image collection.

Comment: OH so I'm able to use the sat[0] and it pulls the first element? I had thought that for lists it was only going to work if I did sat.get(0). Yes you are right for the images - I am subsetting to points; I'll add that to the code.

Comment: I can also confirm that `print(ee.ImageCollection(ee.String(sat[0])));` does not work

Comment: Did you make a client-side list? It won't work with a server-side list (`ee.List()`)

Comment: Ohh I see, my bad. Gotcha, thank you!